# I disagree with the closing of my question

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

The question is [Node.js CMS with internal search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15047094/node-js-cms-with-internal-search)

I've read the post about non-Stack OverFlow questions, but that's not this case. Searching for a Node.js implementation of search **are not a good fit for this site ?**. Maybe those people who closed it, never use this CMS based on Node or doesn't like it at all or this question is for [Seasoned Advice](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: You're certainly right that it's not for Seasoned Advice :-)

Answer (score 18):

Your question states:

> At Node.js github wiki page we have a list of CMS and static blog engines. Can you tell me which item of them comes with internal search modules, not Google Site Search like npmjs.org. I am interested in the implementation of Sphinx or Solr with Node.js for training purposes.

This is essentially asking people to go through a list of CMS, lookup their features and make you another list of the ones that contain a search.

IMHO, it is not a programming question, as you aren't really coding anything here. Stack Overflow is for help with programming problems. You are simply asking *which* CMSes *contain* a search feature, rather than something like "I'm using Foo CMS, and it has a search feature. However, I can't get this to work, due to Bar exception. Here is the log and the relevant code".

So really, your question is a product suggestion, not a programming question. This makes it off topic.

Comment: Thanks, but i think if i'm looking for realization in a wild - that mean that I want to get into the code, because there are very few examples

Comment: @khaljava It is great that you want to get into code here, but your question was still asking for a product list. If you went through the list you linked to and checked up on the features of each CMS, you'd end up with the same list. You are more than welcome to try using the CMSes from that list and coming to stack overflow if you face a problem with the code.

Comment: @Raghav_Sood at this week i already tried a half of the list). And very thank you, I understood my mistake. Now I will write more specifically.

Answer (score -6):

Stack Overflow is also for programming tools questions.  While your question could have been worded better, it is appropriate to ask a specific question about a tool.  I often want to know if a specific tool has a specific feature that can be implemented in a specific way.

I've edited your question a little and cast a vote to re-open.

Comment: I'm sorry, but even with the edit I think that essentially asking *"Does any system in a list on this external site have feature X?"* still doesn't make a good question for the site.

Comment: @Bart, I understand that it is that, but I see it as a request for a specific tool with a specific feature.  It's obviously 'listy', but at some point when you need a tool, you have to ask a question that way.  It's very hard sometimes from product propaganda/documentation to determine details of featuresets of products.

Comment: Sure, I'm not arguing that it's not a fair question for a developer to have. But I don't see it as a question fit for Stack Overflow. Perhaps it's worth taking it to a topic appropriate chatroom? The OP just has enough rep for that.

Comment: @LanceRoberts thank you for editing, i understood my mistake.

Comment: @khaljava, just be aware, Bart is right, it's not really a great fit for Stack Overflow, list-type questions don't fit in well, so it probably won't get reopened.  It would have been better if you had done research and then asked the question on the engines that you weren't able to determine the answer on.

Comment: A CMS isn't a 'programming tool' or a feature of one, neither.

Comment: @Rosinante, valid point.